# Remove & add split-list using dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
for iterate in message_split:
   if(iterate == emotion):
      message_split.remove(iterate)
       message_split = emotion.get(" ", "!")
```

I tried to remove and add on the same index after taking input from user using split function but it's returning the split list instead of running for loop. i want to replace the iterate with emotion key value

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you show us the entire code? What is `message_split` and `emotion`?

Comment: Found the answer, Thanks for reaching out